# Possible to change Quick-Reply buttons in Mail Notifications?

Tags: mail.app, macos

Yosemite introduced a new feature to quick reply within a notification.

Mail offers the options to trash a new E-Mail or reply to it. **But, instead of trash, I want to archive it.**

Can I change somewhere the buttons/behaviour within notifications?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is impossible for now, but will hopefully be in next year's release. All that I've seen that you can do to is to style notifications [by changing button names and menu title](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel) and with [Mjolnir](https://github.com/asmagill/mjolnir_asm.ui/issues/1#issuecomment-68453134). Beyond that isn't built in to the API yet.

[Similar question here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114327/is-it-possible-to-code-a-reply-to-facebook-messages-in-notification-centre-in)

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to examine the source for iMessage and Mail to recreate the interaction?